# UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013

I have two sites that were originally migrated from SPS2003.  It worked well in SharePoint 2007 and even on SharePoint 2010,  however when we migrated it to SharePoint 2013,  the home page throws following errors on the ULS Log.

> 5/24/2013 09:57:46.62  w3wp.exe (0x0D50)   0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation
>   Files   ak8dj   High
>   UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)

---

> 05/24/2013 09:57:46.62 w3wp.exe (0x0D50)   0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation   Cobalt  ajoii   Medium
>   Mapping Store error to Cobalt error. [Store Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocParams(SqlSession session, Guid guidSiteId, Int32 cbContent, Nullable`1 parentId, Guid docId, Nullable`1 level, SPChunkedArray`1 rgbContent, Byte[] rgbRbsId, Int64 bsn, Byte partition, Int32 pageSize, Boolean bStartFilling)

---

> 05/24/2013 09:57:46.62 w3wp.exe (0x0D50)   0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation   Cobalt  aintx   High    Failed in CobaltStream.LockBytes: ErrorException --- Error: Unknown (Win32=0x80004003) --- Error message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocParams(SqlSession session, Guid guidSiteId, Int32 cbContent, Nullable`1 parentId, Guid docId, Nullable`1 level, SPChunkedArray`1 rgbContent, Byte[] rgbRbsId, Int64 bsn, Byte partition, Int32 pageSize, Boolean bStartFilling)     at

---

> 05/24/2013 09:57:46.64 w3wp.exe (0x0D50)   0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at

---

> 05/24/2013 09:57:46.64 w3wp.exe (0x0D50)   0x1D24  SharePoint Foundation   Database    ab1a9   High    Failed to get document content data. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocParams(SqlSession session, Guid guidSiteId, Int32 cbContent, Nullable`1 parentId, Guid docId, Nullable`1 level, SPChunkedArray`1 rgbContent, Byte[] rgbRbsId, Int64 bsn, Byte partition, Int32 pageSize, Boolean bStartFilling)     at

I could not find any materials related to this on the internet,  I am not even sure if it has to do something with SPS2003 compatibility.

Any help pointers?

Comment: Not an answer here, but I'm getting the same error message [see below] on a new SharePoint 2013 install. I thought I had finished configuring Search for the site, but the search boxes still show no results and I'm still getting errors in the logs like the one you have listed here. "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized. at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer" Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of my pages are customized, unfortunately. Sudhir, when you say "Once I reset the page to site definition ...", is that something you do in SharePoint designer? Just curious. Thanks.

Comment: Yes,  In my case the pages were changed using SharePoint designer,  so I opened the page in SharePoint designer and reset it to Site Definition.  Unfortunately the error message is pretty generic and it does not reveals any information.  Your scenario might be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has the most simplest answer.  I saw that pages in my SharePoint 2007 environment was customized using SharePoint Designer,  Once I reset the page to site definition everything started working (without any errors).

I suspect that when the pages are customized in Designer,  the HTML scripts for pages are taken as it is through database migrations, and SharePoint 2013 is not smart enough to render the customized pages based on old definition.

Learning,  reset Designer customized pages to site definition in case site throws error after migration.  This means that you will have to lose all your customization.

Please feel free to post any better answer, in case you find one...

Weird but true...

Comment: I'm getting the same error only I'm getting it on when I open my custom InfoPath 2010 form with code behind that I have running in my SP2013 farm.  The form still opens, no issues posting form to site collection or saving data to lists from within the form, just get a lot of these 1 liner errors when I open and close.  Any thoughts?  Is this something that I just need to worry about?  Would this happen if I upgraded the form to SP2013 format?

Comment: Also, is the above answer the only answer to customized forms created in SharePoint Designer?  Has anyone come up with a better way to fix than resetting to site definition?  I'd rather not lose any customizations.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error when an InfoPath tried to pull the User information through a User Profile service (GetUserProfilebyName). I followed the steps in this post and was able to resolve the issue.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/rajbugga/archive/2013/08/07/infopath-over-claims-authentication-sharepoint-2010-amp-2013.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a file ghosting issue in your master page. A file that was uploaded before and ghosted doesn't exist any more. You can revert back to the original master page or go through the master page and webparts to find the offending component. However if you run a SQL profiler you may be able to locate the exact component. Trial and error is often faster in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to View or Edit Properties on Site Pages I had just made. I tried resetting to Site Definition and it did not help. Then I tried Checking in the page, Publish it, and then tried to Edit Properties and it worked. Don't know why but try it if Resetting site definition does not work.